# Deriving the type of (foldr (.))

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

I'm trying to manually derive the type of (foldr (.))

```
foldr :: (a1 -> b1 -> b1) -> b1 -> [a1] -> b1
(.) ::(b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b2) -> a2 -> c2
```

Then:

```
a1 ~ (b2 -> c2)
b1 ~ (a2 -> b2)
b1 ~ a2
```

So I get that `(foldr (.)) :: (a2 -> b2) -> [(b2 -> c2)] -> (a2 -> b2)`

But GHCi returns: `:t (foldr (.)) :: (a -> b) -> [b -> b] -> a -> b`

Why b2 and c2 are the same?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Comment: You realise you're contradicting yourself with `b1 ~ (a2 -> b2)` ∧ `b1 ~ a2`? (Actually it's not really contradiction, but it'd be an "infinite type" which you can't have in Haskell.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout But if I query GHCi for the type of (foldr (.)) I get (a -> b) -> [b -> b] -> a -> b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the type of `(.)` as

```
(b2 -> c2) -> (a2 -> b2) -> (a2 -> c2)
```

then

```
b1 ~ (a2 -> b2)
b1 ~ (a2 -> c2)
```

so `(b2 ~ c2)`

then you can see the type of `(foldr (.))` is

```
(a2 -> b2) -> [(b2 -> b2)] -> (a2 -> b2)
```

which is the type GHC derives.