# Inferring type of composed function Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, composition

Im having trouble inferring the type of this function:

```
(foldr (.))
```

I know the types of:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

But now i have no idea what to do.. Is there a method to always be able to infer the type in a systematic way? How would it apply to this case?

Comment: you can ask ghci: using `:t`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deriving the type of (foldr (.))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417844/deriving-the-type-of-foldr)

Answer (score 4):

I usually follow these steps:

Write their types:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Make all the type variable name distinct:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
foldr :: (x -> y -> y) -> y -> [x] -> y
```

Now since you are applying `(.)` to the first argument of `foldr`, you can infer the following relation between the types:

```
foldr :: (   x ->       y ->         y  ) -> y -> [x] -> y
(.) ::   (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

From the above you can infer the following relationship:

```
x ~ (b -> c)
y ~ (a -> b)
y ~ (a -> c)
```

From the above `y`, you can infer that both `b` and `c` should be same.

The type of `foldr (.)` should be:

```
foldr (.) :: y -> [x] -> y
```

Now replace `y` and `x` with the new derived ones, you will get the required type:

```
foldr (.) :: (a -> b) -> [b -> b] -> a -> b
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. My only question is, how did you know where to put the parenthesis? By this i mean, couldnt you parenthesized the expression so that x ~ b, y ~ c->a->b, y~ a->c . in this case the type inference is completely different.

Comment: @user3558296 That's because the type of `(.)` is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. The parenthesis part is already fixed for `(.)`.

Comment: thanks a lot i get it now.. Now i was trying to infer the type of (. flip) using the method you explain and i got : [code] (b -> a -> c1 -> c) -> a -> b -> c1 -> c[/code] however ghci says the type is [code] ((b -> a -> c1) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c1) -> c[/code] why does ghci parenthesize the b->a->c1 expression?